# 'database-agnostic' tag should be 'dbms-agnostic'

Tags: discussion, tagging

I had a recent question tagged with `database-agnostic` and I thought, that's strange, couldn't most questions be similarly tagged? Put another way, wouldn't a question about a specific database be off-topic? How many shared databases are available to us from a DBA perspective?

Then I realised: they meant `DBMS-agnostic`. However, I couldn't find a tag for that. Conclusion: the tag is misnamed.

How to get this fixed?

Just to be clear, I am aware it is common to use 'database' as a contraction of DBMS (it is after all three syllables compared with four!) And no doubt there are some of us that think SQL Server **is** a database. However, I understand this site is about learning and that precise language is important for something as high level and oft used as a tag.

FWIW the vast majority of `database-` tags use the word appropriately. The only other inappropriate one I could spot was `database-internals`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a well-argued and sensible suggestion, but I personally think that while the principle of using of precise language is a good one, in this case there is no precise language to choose.

As can be seen on the Oracle site [here](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/index.html) and the SQL Server site [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server), 'DBMS' has almost completely disappeared in favour of 'database'.

Comment: The SQL Server example says "Database Platform" rather than just the word "Database" though.

Comment: Not consistently though, eg "SQL Server is the least vulnerable database for six years"